# Battery Packs not showing any voltage on multimeter

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, voltage-measurement

I made 4 battery packs with 10 batteries in series each using a spot welder. Each of the batteries in each pack are 1.37V, but when they are connected, the voltage is shown at zero. I took the batteries in one battery pack apart after I measured this and tested each one separately, and they each read 1.37V, but when I test them when they are connected via the metal ribbon, they read 0v.

I tested the nickel strips I spot-welded them on and they are conductive. So I don't understand why they aren't reading anything. I couldn't even get a 3v LED to light up, and just to check to make sure the LED did light up but just blew, I tested it on a 3v power supply and it lit.

I do know, however that there is current in the battery packs. I was mounting the batteries wires thru a hole in my robot, and somehow there was a very brief short-circuit and I got burned. (I'm pretty sure the batteries are just fine).

Comment: Photo and schematic, please.

Comment: Sounds like you hooked up your batteries wrong.

Comment: Why don't you try hooking up just 2 batteries first. If that works, keep adding more batteries one at a time. Either you will be successful or you will find out what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Or the multimeter is hooked up wrong (or on the wrong setting, or has a blown fuse)

Comment: Did you connect them in series and in opposite direction?  The front end (+) of one battery has to connect to the back end (-) of the other or they push in opposite directions.

Comment: @KH, Yes I did.

Comment: @Circuit-B0ARD Yes you did what?  Hook them up in opposite direction or did you connect the front end to the back end of the next?